# OpenSSL Commands inside ADB Shell

Tags: android, shell, openssl, adb

I just have one simple doubt. 
Can I run openssl commands like encrypt/decrypt/verify within the adb shell command prompt?

P.S. - 
I have a rooted device. 
And I am inside the adb shell command prompt. Now I want to run the openssl command inside this prompt.

I know we have openssl library inside the system/lib but so far from what I have learnt we can use that only through conscrypt jar.

But can we use it from adb shell? 
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL consist from 3 parts: libssl.so libcrypto.so and openssl command line tool. Last seems to be not compiled and you should cross compile by yourself. libssl.so libcrypto.so there is in system/lib. see http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android